# XML-RPC and post_date

Tags: posts, date, xml-rpc

I'm trying to set the post_date via XML-RPC and keep getting an error saying the XML isn't formatted properly. The code goes something like:

```
$post = get_post( $post_id );

$response = $client->query( 
    'wp.editPost',
    array( 
        0, 
        $user, 
        $pw, 
        array( 
            'post_date' => $post->post_date 
        ) 
    ) 
);
```

I'm hitting the same issue with `wp.newPost`. I know the date should be formatted ISO8601 but I'm just having no luck getting it formatted right.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618142/wordpress-set-post-date

Comment: Oh I've been there mulitple times. If it's on the 1st 3 pages of Google results I've tried it. That exact string comes back with and invalid formatting issue.

Comment: I guess you're simply missing a `,` in here: ` 'wp.editPost' array` between the Array and the method. You should turn on your debugging environment to catch typos and (even better), use a decent IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here.  First of all, `wp.editPost` takes a fourth parameter before the content struct -> the ID of the post you're trying to edit (should be an integer).

Second, you're passing a string for the `post_date`, so the client automatically converts this to a `<string>` tag before sending it to the server ... unfortunately, the server expects a `<dateTime.iso8601>` tag.

You can fix this by parsing the string date and passing an instance of the `IXR_Date` class instead.  The client will parse it properly and the server will react appropriately.  I've tested the following scenario on my own server:

```
$date = new IXR_Date( strtotime( $post->post_date ) );  // Parse the date to an IXR_Date object.

$response = $client->query( 
    'wp.editPost',
    array( 
        0, 
        $user, 
        $pwd,
        $post_id,
        array( 
            'post_date' => $date 
        ) 
    ) 
);
```

Comment: Ooops on the missed field. I did actually have it (or the other content wouldn't be updating when I had the date commented out).